# Android Grid with differant cell heights

Tags: android, android-layout, datagridview, grid

I am trying to create a Grid in android having a fixed number of columns and the items in these columns to fit tightly (something like the new Google+ web layout).
[image]

This is the effect I am looking for and I see quite a few apps using something like this where the cells wrap the content.
I tried a GridView but that just causes the cells to overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small library based on the StaggeredGridView that surfaced in the ACL. I could not get the existing library to work so based it on the orignal implementation. There is also a demo app. [Staggered Grid View](https://github.com/Utopia-Developers/StaggeredGridView)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView). Demo for the library is [here](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo).

Comment: I tried that.Its what I am looking for but for me it does not work.I can scroll down but not up.I have filled an issue in the repo.